# Facebook Like button using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

My knowledge of Facebook's PHP SDK is limited at this point but is it possible to use their PHP SDK to create a text link version of their 'Like' button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, I'm afraid this is not possible.

Comment: This is most upsetting! Thanks @ifaour

Comment: The good thing is, it won't really affect the *look & feel* of your website because the users are probably used to it by now.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using the Like button as well as the like box on our Website but the JS SDK has a kind of high execution time and takes a while to load and thus I am currently looking for a proper way to avoid the JS SDK.

The Like button can - more or less - be replaced with the Graph API whereas the like box can't.

To set a like for an object (website, photo, link, whatever) you can simply call the graph api with the method=post Parameter.

```
<?php

    require_once("facebook.php"); //from the FB SDK 
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'your_app_id';
    $config['secret'] = 'your_app_secret';
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if(!$user){
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_stream, user_likes', 'redirect_uri'=>'www.example.com'));
    }
    if($user){
        try{
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $attend = "https://graph.facebook.com/www.example.com/like?method=post&access_token=".$access_token;
            file($attend);
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            $user = NULL;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Please login via Facebook</a>';
    }
?>
```

You'll need an FB Application though, as you have to specify the app_id and app_secret for the PHP SDK, which you don't have to when you are using just the like button.

Answer (score 0):

There's a /likes graph API object that the docs say you can write to with the proper permissions. I've never tried it though.

Comment: Do you have a link? I'm aware of read only access to /[ID]/likes with an access_token.